# line cuts off/does not print at next page in Jasper

Tags: java, oracle, jasper-reports, ireport

As I was generating sample outputs for my reports in Jasper iReport, I noticed something. As I was paging along the preview, everything was fine like this:

[image: paging through preview of report 1]
[image: paging through preview of report 2]

I configured the vertical lines on the table to adjust whenever any of the fields stretch upon overflow. But then, I get to Page 9 and this is what happens:

[image: line cuts off, does not print 1]
[image: line cuts off, does not print 2]

The vertical lines at this page don't seem to print/are cut because the record at the top of the table is still part of the last record from the previous page. My question now is, how do I fix or prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, I got it. I looked at the **Properties** of the vertical lines in the table, and I just checked the `"Print When Detail Overflows"` **checkbox**.